# static getDerivedStateFromProps does't behave like componentwillreceiveprops?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm trying to implement search in child component , the parent component will get data from server and pass that data to child component

as props, now child component has to implement search on that data, I have used `componentwillreceiveprops` which is depreciated how can I implement 
this without using  `componentwillreceiveprops`, below is my code

[working example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lghbdrn/1/)

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: []
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            // mimic api call
            const data = [
                { key: 'react'}, { key: 'redux'},
                { key: 'javascript' }, { key: 'Ruby'} ,{key: 'angular'}
            ]
            setTimeout(this.setState({data}), 3000);
        }


        render() {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <ChildComponent data = {this.state.data}/>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }


    class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: []
            }
        }

        componentwillreceiveprops(nextProps){
            this.setState({data: nextProps.data})

        }

        search(e){
            console.log('props,', e.target.value)
            let searchedData =  this.props.data.filter(el => {
                return el.key.startsWith(e.target.value)
            })
            this.setState({data: searchedData})
        };

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    search for (react, redux, angular, ruby)
                    <br/> <br/> <br/>
                    <input type = 'text' onChange={this.search.bind(this)}/>
                    {this.state.data.map(d => {
                        return (<div key={d.key}>{d.key}</div>)
                    })}
                </div>
            )
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're not using any conditions inside componentWillReceiveProps. Why do you even need it or `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is not a direct replacement for `componentWillReceiveProps`. Its just meant to update state in response to any update and unlike `componentWillReceiveProps`, getDerivedStateFromProps is triggered on every update either from child or from parent so you cannot simply update state without any conditional check. In order to update state if the props changed, you need to store the previous props in the state of child too or update the key of child so that it triggers a re-render

There are two possible approaches to this. Below is an example of first approach with `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import "./styles.css";
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // mimic api call
    const data = [
      { key: "react" },
      { key: "redux" },
      { key: "javascript" },
      { key: "Ruby" },
      { key: "angular" }
    ];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState(prev => ({ data: [...prev.data, { key: "Golang" }] }));
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComponent data={this.state.data} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (!_.isEqual(props.data, state.prevData)) {
      return {
        data: props.data,
        prevData: state.data
      };
    } else {
      return {
        prevData: props.data
      };
    }
  }

  search(e) {
    console.log("props,", e.target.value);
    let searchedData = this.props.data.filter(el => {
      return el.key.startsWith(e.target.value);
    });
    this.setState({ data: searchedData });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        search for (react, redux, angular, ruby)
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.search.bind(this)} />
        {this.state.data.map(d => {
          return <div key={d.key}>{d.key}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

**[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/kxq3pzj3wv)**

---

Second approach involves changing the key of the child component instead of implementing `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import _ from "lodash";

import "./styles.css";
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      keyData: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // mimic api call
    const data = [
      { key: "react" },
      { key: "redux" },
      { key: "javascript" },
      { key: "Ruby" },
      { key: "angular" }
    ];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(prev => ({ data, keyData: (prev.keyData + 1) % 10 }));
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState(prev => ({
          data: [...prev.data, { key: "Golang" }],
          keyData: (prev.keyData + 1) % 10
        }));
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComponent data={this.state.data} key={this.state.keyData} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.data
    };
  }

  search(e) {
    console.log("props,", e.target.value);
    let searchedData = this.props.data.filter(el => {
      return el.key.startsWith(e.target.value);
    });
    this.setState({ data: searchedData });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        search for (react, redux, angular, ruby)
        <br /> <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.search.bind(this)} />
        {this.state.data.map(d => {
          return <div key={d.key}>{d.key}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

**[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/lpoyr4pv7z)**

You can go ahead with the second method when you know that you will have quite a few updates in the child component whereas update from parent will be less frequent and the props that you have to compare `getDerivedStateFromProps` is nested . In such as case implementing `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be less performant than updating the key since you will need to perform expensive computation on each render.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your `componentWillReceiveProps()` behavior using the new `getDerivedStateFromProps()` method, you can replace your current `componentwillreceiveprops()` hook with this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, state){

    /* Return the new state object that should result from nextProps */
    return { data : nextProps.data }
}
```

The `getDerivedStateFromProps()` will be called before your component is rendered and, if a non-null value is returned, then that return value will become the state of the component.

In your case, the state of the `<ChildComponent>` component has only one `data` field which is populated directly from props, so returning `{ data : nextProps.data }` would be sufficent to update the `data` state field to match the incoming `data` prop.

The general idea is that you can use this method to update a component's state based on changing/incoming props.

[See this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) for more information on `getDerivedStateFromProps()` - hope that helps!

#### Update

Also on another note, it seems the way `<Parent>` is updating state via the `setTimeout` method is incorrect. You should update it as follows:

```
// Incorrect: setTimeout(this.setState({data}), 3000);

setTimeout(() => this.setState({data}), 3000);
```

Comment: @shaan just extended answer - does this help?

Comment: I'm not using setTimeout it  just mimic api call